# Foreach Loop Container failed to traverse through all files in a folder

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have one temp folder `C:\Mydata` inside that i have `.csv` files with name
`demo1.csv` `demo2.csv`...etc

Now I want to insert data from all those files into database table

for this I have taken `Foreach Loop Container` in the property `Directory` I mention
`C:\Mydata`
inside `Foreach Loop Container` taken a `Data Flow Task` in that `Flat File Source` is there in the connection manager property in `file name` what should I mention, so that it will traverse through all folder and all files whose extension is `.csv`
I did like `C:\DEMO\*.csv` which is giving me error :
`no file found path is wrong`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what i interpreted, your issue was assigning the resulting file from the foreach to the connector.

To do that you need to assign the filename from the Foreach to a variable.

The first step to be taken is to create the variable. To do that you need to activate the "Variables" window:
[image: Activating "Variables" window]

Then you need to create a new variable of type string and rename it.

[image: Creating a new varible]

For more information on SSIS variables and how to create them, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140216.aspx

Now you need to assign the new variable (in this case i named it "filename") to the foreach loop:
[image: foreach loop steps]
**NOTE THAT WHILE THE OPTION "Name Only" IS SELECTED IN THE FIRST WINDOW, IN YOUR CASE YOU PROBABLY WANT "Fully Qualified"!!**

The screenshot was taken from a working project i have and i am using only the name (Name Only) as opposed to the full path (Fully Qualified)

After doing that you need to assign that variable to your flat file connector using expressions:

[image: setting your connector]

Comment: thanks but what is the value of variable :
@[User:filename] ? need to keep it like .csv??

Comment: The variable @[User::filename] is created in the "Variables" window. It will contain the current file path the foreach is currently iterating. I will add a link to the answer showing how to create a variable and using it ASAP.

Answer (score 2):

Which version of MSSQL and SSIS are you using? And why are you using C:\Mydata in one place and C:\DEMO in another?

The basic technique of looping over files is described [here](http://www.sqlis.com/sqlis/post/Looping-over-files-with-the-Foreach-Loop.aspx).

There is lot of information about these steps in the documentation and on the web. If you need more help, please be as specific as possible about what you've tried, what isn't working, what versions you're working with etc.