# fetch filename along with values into excel sheet

Tags: ssis

I have an input folder, which consists of few files with .wsr and .wsw format. i need to fetch the file name and few values inside the file name and load it into excel file.

[image: Accured Income with BL CUSIP.wsw]

i have attached my sample input file, from that file , i need to take **filename, Key, Title, Category**

and my output inside excel has to be like.
[image: otput].

i need to use for each loop cnatiner to fetch this files.

Answer (score 1):

To use the for each loop container, see the answer to this: [Foreach Loop Container failed to traverse through all files in a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308616/foreach-loop-container-failed-to-traverse-through-all-files-in-a-folder)

The link above, however, creates a solution where you parse a csv file. In this case you will need to do your custom parsing by code. I would use a script task to extract that info from the file.

In this link you have examples on how to use a script task: http://www.programmersedge.com/?p=1350

In the custom script you will be creating you need to open the file with a streamReader and extract the relevant information. The following link has a nice tutorial on how to use the streamreader in C#: http://www.dotnetperls.com/streamreader

Comment: HI Cfrag,  My files are of .wsw format. As i shown above i have attached sample file. i need to fetch the filename, and some more columns inside the file.

Comment: I am sorry. Forgot to mention to look only to the part about how to construct the foreach loop. As long as the file is a text file, you can open in in the script task with a FileStream. However, that will require some programming knowledge. I am updating the answer to reflect what i am saying in this comment.